# How to remove all apps in memory through UIAutomators?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I wanted to remove all Apps that is in memory for a clean start. If I know the apps in memory, that could be done as follow

```
    try
    {
        getUiDevice().pressRecentApps();
        UiObject uio = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("apps one"));
        uio.swipeRight(20);
        uio = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("facebook"));
        uis.swipeRight(20);

    }
    catch (RemoteException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, what I wanted is not knowing the list of current Apps, I just want to open up the Apps List in memory, and swipe them away. Is there a way to write a For-Loop for that getting the list of Apps in memory through UiAutomator API?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
try
    {
        getUiDevice().pressRecentApps();
        UiObject uio = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.systemui:id/recent_item"));
        while uio.exists(){
            uio.swipeRight(20);
            uio = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("facebook"));
            uis.swipeRight(20);
            UiObject uio = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("apps one"));
    }
    catch (RemoteException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Later Update:

Instead of text("apps one") use a view property like class name resource id.
You can see these in the android monitor (you can find it in platform tools). 
Select the device in the left and then press the button next to the screen capture one. 
This will generate all views on screen and you can see the layout of the recent apps panel.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. But the problem is, I don't know the "text" to be used if I really want to do an arbitrary apps select and remove them from memory. i.e. I don't know "apps one", "facebook" etc...

Comment: Looking at the uiautomatorviewer or from the Android will know the name. Is it possible to programmatically get the name instead? (or not knowing the name, just automatically traverse through all the apps listed in the memory, would works for me as well).

Comment: Every recent app is placed in a view with the resource id "com.android.systemui:id/recent_item". So, while this view exists, there would be recent apps in the recent apps window.

There is nothing wrong with this approach. You need to identify the views somehow. Or you could use a flag when starting the apps to make them not to show in the recent apps screen.